# How to login multiple users with different inputs in different threads in JMeter using CSV data set config

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I am using the CSV data set config for login multiple users, but cannot read the parameter.

[Thread group screenshort](http://prntscr.com/8rh0ed).

CSV data set config screenshot: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8rh09c)

Http request default page : [Screenshot](http://prnt.sc/8rh0my)

login parameter screenshot :  [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8rh002)

View result tree screenshot: [Screenshot](http://prnt.sc/8rh09c)

I have done all above processes but not able to solve the problem.
Other screenshots are added in comment.

Can someone explain all process step by step.

Comment: Explain all process step by step. 
I am use the CSV data set config for login multiple users, but cannot read the parameter.
Thread group screenshort : http://prntscr.com/8rh0ed
CSV data set config screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8rh09c
Http request default page : http://prntscr.com/8rh0my
login parameter screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8rh002
View result tree screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8rh1dp
I have done all above process but not solve the problem.

Comment: Added the screenshots in the main question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ${email} instead of $(email) also for password.
You can check details in previously [answered question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798273/use-csv-parameters-in-jmeter-httprequest-path/8800525#8800525)

Comment: Thank for you answer but this process is can not work. I have perform the process but same result produce

Answer (score 0):

The issue which you are facing is because of the wrong usage of parameter syntax in your script. You have used `login = $(email) and password = &(password)` which is wrong way of declaring and using CSV file parameters in JMeter. The correct syntax is `${parametername}` for using parameters in JMeter.

So use,

```
login = ${email}
password = ${password}
```

and your script will work fine, remember name of parameters is case sensitive. Go through this [link](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) for more details.